# Accessing DisplayName of OrgWideEmailAddress in Email Template

Tags: email, email-template

How can I insert the DisplayName of OrgWideEmailAddress in the email template like how we can access the fields of other objects? E.g. I can access the name of the user by using {!User.Name}. I tried using {!OrgWideEmailAddress.DisplayName} but it doesn't work. I even tried creating a custom label but even that didn't seem to help. Any help regarding this is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using custom template/ visualforce template?

Comment: No, I am using HTML template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With standard HTML templates you're limited to some pretty basic merge fields, either global ones, e.g. $Organization, recipient specific ones (User/Contact/Lead), or the merge object and you'll only get one.

This may be possible with Visualforce Email templates with some creative thinking, but even that may be difficult.  You can do queries in the email template via components, but you only get the recipient and related to ids, which aren't going to tell you anything about which from address you're using.

All in all, it looks like you may just need to create multiple templates with the different signatures for the different from address display names.